# Next.js 13 with app dir does not add meta tags to Raw HTML

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I've been using the latest Canary version of Next.js (13.1.7-canary.21 at the moment) **with the app dir** and I've tried to the head.tsx, Metadata and even directly to the head tag under html tag on layout.tsx and all 3 solutions do not add the meta tags to the Raw HTML (when checking with right click > View Source Code), only in the rendered page. In the Raw version all I see is the script tags with `self.__next_f` assignments sourcing or JS chunks that will render into the real content.

Example:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js" nomodule=""></script> </head>

<body>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-89a6dfefe710a06e.js" async=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/679-e73c65c61694e4b8.js" async=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app-72dd08d1d4e4deae.js" async=""></script>
    <script>
        (self.__next_f=self.__next_f||[]).push([0])
    </script>
    <script>
        self.__next_f.push([1,"0:\"$L1\"\n"])
    </script>
            <script>
        self.__next_f.push([1,"3:[[[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"charSet\":\"utf-8\"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"name\":\"viewport\",\"content\":\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"}],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]],[[\"$\",\"link\",null,{\"rel\":\"canonical\",\"href\":\"https://example.com/\"}],null,null,null],null,null,[null,null,null,null,null],null,null,null,null,null]\n"])
    </script>
```

By the way, the code above is from a production deploy to Vercel.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I'm not using `'use client'` in the layout.tsx so not sure why that's not added during build.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with nextjs 13.2.4. I followed the official documentation at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata.
No matter if I use `export const metadata = { ... }` or `export async function generateMetadata`, the meta tags are not included in the static html code. Instead, it is included in the `self.__next_f.push(` which is not found by opengraph crawlers

Comment: Okay after 3 days of troubleshooting... The problem was, that my layout.tsx used a client component which made use of the hook useSearchParams. This hook apparently broke static rendering completely so the meta tags were not statically generated in the index.html.

Just removing the hook useSearchParams did the trick